# Gradle Plugin Duplicate Version Artifactory Search

Tags: java, plugins, gradle, artifactory

I am trying to apply a plugin on a project that is a company specific findbugs plugin. In my Parent gradle project I have the following:

```
dependencies {  
    findbugs 'com.google.code.findbugs.findbugs:3.0.1'
    findbugs configurations.findbugsPlugins.dependencies
    // Here we specify the findbugsPlugins
    findbugsPlugins 'com.company.common.company-findbugs-plugin:1.01'
}  
task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    classes = fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/*.class");
    source = fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/*.java");
    classpath = files()
    pluginClasspath = project.configurations.findbugsPlugins
    findbugs {
        toolVersion = "3.0.1"
        sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
        ignoreFailures = true
        reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/findbugsReports")
        effort = "max"
        reportLevel = "high"
        includeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/include.xml")
        excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/exclude.xml")
    }
tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    reports {
            xml.enabled = false
            html.enabled = true
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I build the project, the build fails with an exception reporting:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':findbugsPlugins'.
> Could not find com.company.common.company-findbugs-plugin:1.01:.
   Searched in the following locations:     

http://artifactory.company.com:8081/artifactory/repo/com/company/common/company-findbugs-plugin/1.01//1.01-.pom
  http://artifactory.company.com:8081/artifactory/repo/com/company/common/company-findbugs-plugin/1.01//1.01-.jar
  Required by:                
     com.company.project:ProjectName1.0.4
```

Any reason why gradle is adding the version twice at the end of the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have incorrectly defined the Gradle dependency, colon is missing between GroupId and ArtifactId**:

```
'com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:3.0.1'
```

and the same most likely applies for

```
'com.company.common:company-findbugs-plugin:1.01'
```